# Drupal: Access A Field in hook_views_query_alter()

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-views-relationship

I have `content type` **picture** which has a field with the `machine name` **score**. I have implemented the `hook_views_query_alter()` which looks like the following; the main part is that I add a line which adds an extra where condition:

```
function pic_anlysis_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) 
{
    ...
    $query->where[1]['conditions'][2] = array('field'=>"node.score","value"=>array(30, 60),"operator"=>"BETWEEN");
}
```

But the above doesn't work; I think that node.score is the wrong key used to represent the field in the query. Anyone knows what I should use instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Fields are not stored in node table.

Try

```
$query->add_where(1, 'field_data_field_score.value', array(30, 60), 'BETWEEN');
```

Comment: I think that's the solution, but further steps are necessary. Do I need to add the field_data_field_score as a relation to the view? I look at the database, and you are quite correct, but now the view completely fails. In the database, the following would be the table and column that store the information: field_data_field_score.field_score_value.